Customize "AssemblyName Wants to Use domain.com to Sign In" message on iOS
In my iOS app, I am using Auth0 as an authentication provider. When redirecting to Auth0 for login, iOS will display a dialog that says
{AssemblyName} Wants to Use {auth0Domain} to Sign In

How can I customize this message to show the name of my app instead of the aseembly name?
As per Auth0 instructions, I have added the following to Info.plist
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>{My Display Name}</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>{My Custom Scheme}</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
    </dict>
</array>


I have also added a custom CFBundleDisplayName.
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>{ My Display Name }</string>

However, when the redirect needs to happen, the popup shows my full Assembly name instead of my friendly display name. Is there any way to customize this?
I am using .Net Maui to build my app, but I don't think this is a Maui specific problem.
